# Generate a `link_to` to the controller action `edit`, dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dynamic, link-to

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to generate a `link_to` to the controller action `edit`, *dynamically*. I have to use it in a partial template but the issue is that I am rendering that same partial template for different model data (that is, I pass local variables of different class instances in that).

So I can not use the route "magical RoR way"

```
`edit_<singular_name_of_the_resource>_path(<resource_class_instance>)`.
```

I would like to make something like the following:

```
link_to( @resource_class_instance, :action => 'edit') # This example is wrong, but it suggests the idea
```

**Is it possible? If so, how can I do that?**

Comment: you want to use `link_to` within a controller action?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write routes using the "array style" like this :

```
= link_to "Edit", [:edit, @your_resource]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `edit_polymorphic_url` and (`edit_polymorphic_path`) helper available:
[https://github.com/rails/.../polymorphic_routes.rb#L32](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.7/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L32)