# Showing two types of "posts" in same view mixed together (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I have two models...a designs model and products model that are almost identical but they are both nested in different models (one is nested in collection model and the other in assortment model). So to create a product you first have to create an assortment then create the product in the assortment.

I would like to show (in the view) all of the designs and all of the products mixed together sorted by date.

How can I accomplish this? The way I have it now (which is a weak solution) is i have one page that separates the two...but this is tacky and not user friendly.

I know this post is lean and short so if you would like a better explanation, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
things = Design.all.to_a.concat Product.all.to_a
things.sort! {|t1, t2| t1.date <=> t2.date} #or whatever the date field is called
```

Comment: Based on this, what would to do if you were to have links that go to each product or designs "show page"?

Comment: I think you should just be able to use link to on each individual product/design, see [this stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706448/generate-a-link-to-to-the-controller-action-edit-dynamically)

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit more complicated because they are nested..
so the links I originally had were **link_to collection_design_path(design.collection, design)** 
for designs and **link_to assortment_product_path(product.assortment, product)**
 for products

Comment: I could always do an if statement in the view that finds what each belong to and link to those accordingly but thats a lot of logic in the view and not semantic...but if all else fails...

Comment: Perhaps extract it into a helper method